# How to extract something between <!-- --> using VBA?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a page using VBA. I know how to get elements by *id class* and *tag* names. But now I have come across this Tag

```
<!-- <b>IE CODE : 3407004044</b> -->
```

Now after searching on the internet I know that this is a comment in the HTML, but what I'm unable to find is what is the tag name of this element ,if it qualifies as a tag at all. Should I use

```
documnet.getelementsbytagname("!") ?
```

If not, how else can I extract these comments ?

**EDIT:**
I have a bunch of these *td* elements within *tr* elements and I want to extract `IE Code : 3407004044` 
Below is a larger set of HTML code:

```
<tr align="left">
    <td width="50%" class="subhead1">                                                           

    ' this is the part that I want to extract
    <!-- <b>IE CODE : 3108011111</b> -->                                
    </td>
    <td rowspan="9" valign="top">
    <span id="datalist1_ctl00_lbl_p"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste here a little larger snippet to experiment on? The other day, while working with a site I encountered such difficulty when It came to parse data from comments. However, the thing is IE can handle it very efficiently. You are going wrong somewhere else within your script.

Comment: I have added HTML snippet

Comment: It's a comment node. It's not possible to search for it with IE since the browser doesn't support XPath. Though you could simply read all the HTML from the page with `txt = document.documentElement.innerHTML` and then search for targeted code with a regular expression: `IE CODE : \w+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//tr//comment(), "<b>"), "</b>")
```

to get required data

Comment: I don't understand, how do I use it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA. What is the tool/technology do you use? I cannot identify code syntax `documnet.getelementsbytagname()`... It just looks like `document.getElementsByTagName()`... Do you use pure VBA or tool that can accept JavaScript. Can you update your question with exact code that you use

Comment: @Digvijay, oh, I just found out that VBA has no built-in functions that allows to use XPath. I thought it would be something like `document.getElementByXpath()`... But there is a [workaround](https://codingislove.com/parse-html-in-excel-vba/#highlighter_590366) if you still want to try to implement XPath solution...

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try like this, it works if you fix it a bit further:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myString    As String
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim myArr       As Variant

    myString = "<!-- <b>IE CODE : Koj sega e</b> -->blas<hr>My Website " & _
                    "is here<B><B><B><!-- <b>IE CODE : nomer </b> -->" & _
                    "is here<B><B><B><!-- <b>IE CODE : 1? </b> -->"

    myString = Replace(myString, "-->", "<!--")
    myArr = Split(myString, "<!--")

    For cnt = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        If cnt Mod 2 = 1 Then Debug.Print myArr(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

This is what you get:

```
 <b>IE CODE : Koj sega e</b> 
 <b>IE CODE : nomer </b> 
 <b>IE CODE : 1? </b>
```

---

The idea is the following:

- Replace the `-->` with `<!--`
- Split the input by `<!--`
- Take every second value from the array

There are some possible scenarios, where it will not work, e.g. if you have `-->` or `<!--` written somewhere within the text, but in the general case it should be ok.

Comment: But this HTML code is on a web page, to perform this operation on a string I have to first get the string out from the webpage. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Digvijay - the best way I know - google "Beautiful Soup" and invest 2 hours of reading the tutorials :)

Comment: Is it not possible using VBA and internet explorer ? Can getelementsbytagname be used here ?

Comment: @Digvijay - it is. But the beautiful soup is better :)  However, getting HTML to a string in VBA should be findable in Google & SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805389/getting-data-from-html-source-in-vba-excel

Comment: @Vitayata yes I have searched around and I also have used this approach of getting data by `tagname` or `id` or `classname` , my question here is what will be tagname of `<!-- IE CODE : 3407004044 -->` ?. If I know what are tagname of comments I'll be able to extract it using `getelementsbytagname(" ")`

Comment: @Digvijay - I see, I don't know how to do this. But if you can go to Python or any other language that has a good HTML parser https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers this should be a doable task.