# How to retrieve JSON embedded in HTML comments using XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I have HTML output of the form:

```
<!-- wp:uagb/section {"block_id":"e00ee750-246d-46fd-a034-c6dc37497309","contenttype":"exercise","contenttitle":"here is exercise 1","contentname":"Exercise"} -->
<div id="here-is-exercise-1" class="contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-exercise" data-id="e00ee750-246d-46fd-a034-c6dc37497309">
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
   <p>Some stuff</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:uagb/section -->
```

So you have these comments that start with `<!-- wp:uagb/section` and in those comments you have JSON of form

```
{"block_id":"e00ee750-246d-46fd-a034-c6dc37497309","contenttype":"exercise","contenttitle":"here is exercise 1","contentname":"Exercise"}
```

I am trying to form an XPATH query (in PHP) that is of form

```
"Get me all JSON objects that contain parameter `contenttype`"
```

I am pretty proficient with XPATH when it comes to normal DOM extraction, but not quite sure how to go about this. Ideas?

Comment: Is your desired output the whole first comment or just the word `exercise'?

Comment: The JSON object is what is needed

Comment: Then the xpath expression in the first line of your answer (`//comment()[contains(.,'contenttype')]`) should work, why would you need the rest?

Comment: If I just call xpath that way, won't it also return the text 'wp:uagb/section' in returned output?

Comment: No, just the json comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on this post

[Extracting Comments from HTML code using Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686103/extracting-comments-from-html-code-using-xpath)

here is what I came up with:

```
$contenttypes = $xpath->query("//comment()[contains(.,'contenttype')]");
foreach ($contenttypes as $contenttype) {
    preg_match_all("/\\{(.*?)\\}/", $contenttype->data, $matches);
    $data = json_decode(trim($matches[0][0], '"'));
```

And then the data I need is in that $data variable. Didn't realize that `xpath` has built in support for comments!

I am sure someone has a way to get the JSON object in one xpath query. I couldn't figure that out so just went with `preg_match_all`.